# How to use Docx.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have use docx.js for generate docx file, but generaeted docx doenot open. my generated docx file output is

[image]

i have included following js file into my Html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Docx/jszip.js"></script>

<!-- Include main js lib -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Docx/DOCX.js"></script>
```

and javascript function is

```
function test() {
        //alert("test fn call");
        var doc = new DOCXjs();
        doc.text('DOCX.js is a free open source library for generating Microsoft Word Documents using pure client-side JavaScript.');
        //doc.text('It was developed by James Hall at Snapshot Media.');
        var output = doc.output('datauri');

    }
```

when i click button this function will be calling, and also i want to add datatable as a content of word document so how to add content using Docx.js?

Comment: sorry and also i have included this js <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Docx/base64.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to use the docx.js without server, that will not work because it can't load the necessary files.
if you are executing the code on a server then edit the path of  '/blank/' somewhere in the docx.js file

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/blank/' + files[file],
        complete: function(r) {
        //file_data[this.url.replace(/blank_/, '')] = r.responseText;

        zip.add(this.url.replace('/blank/', ''), r.responseText);
        file_count_current ++;

        if (file_count == file_count_current) {                         
        doOutput();
                        }
                    }
                });
```